# How to make Javascript/JQuery object methods accessible throughout HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a single Javascript/JQuery object that would hold many function which could be access through a HTMl page but I keep running into errors. Below is my external JS file

```
function AppPage(settings){
    function save(formid){
        //get form data and save
    };
    function delete(rowid){
        //get rowid and delete via ajax
    }
}
```

Now I would like to initialize the Javascript object and have it accessible throughout

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="../js/app.page.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
               var app_page = new AppPage({
                      base: "http://localhost/app"
               });
          });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <a onclick="app_page.save('save something')">Example Save Link</a>
     <a onclick="app_page.delete('delete something')">Example Delete Link</a>
  </body>
```

When I try calling the functions I just get an error

> ReferenceError: app_page is not defined

How can I organize this better?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<script>
    var app_page = {
        save: function (formid) {
            //get form data and save
        },

        delete: function (rowid) {
            //get rowid and delete via ajax
        },
    }
</script>
```

You can then call them like this:

```
app_page.save("formid")
app_page.delete("rowid")
```

Answer (score 0):

By object I guess you mean constructor function and The definition of constructor 'AppPage' in incorrect.That will not work even in your javascript.

correct way

```
function AppPage(){
   this.save = function(formid){
     //get form data and save
   };
   this.delete = function(rowid){
     //get rowid and delete via ajax
   };
}
var app_page = new AppPage();
```

and If you want it to be an object you have to use following syntax.

```
var app_page = {
   save: function(formid){
     //get form data and save
   },
   delete: function(rowid){
     //get rowid and delete via ajax
   }
};
```

**don't use 'delete', it's a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the child functions of AppPage as properties. You also need to store the `settings` object you're passing in or your child functions will have nothing to reference:

```
function AppPage(settings){

    // Store the settings
    this.settings = settings;

    // Define the "save" method
    this.save = function(formid){
        console.log("Save " + formid + " to " + this.settings.base);
    };

    // Define the "delete" method
    this.delete = function(rowid){
        console.log("Delete " + rowid  + " to " + this.settings.base);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While ill advised to use global variables your `var` before the variable initialization makes it local to the function you defined it in. Remove var before app_page and it will work.

On the other hand i advise you to create a global object of yours where you define all your functionality on.

Also your functions from the app_page object are not exposed you must assign them to the object in which they are defined attaching them to the base object so you get `this.save = function()...`